# GNOME terminal colors won't change

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to change color of text in the white rectangle

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, GNOME terminal version 3.16.2.
I can't find a way to change that, can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add the answer; mark one of the answers you've been given as accepted, or if none satisfies you, write your own answer. By the way, that's the same solution I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

These are the colors of the command prompt.  You need to change your prompt as such:

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[whatever]\$ \e[m"
```

where `0;31` is the color code.

Here's a list of color codes:

```
Color   Code
Black   0;30
Blue    0;34
Green   0;32
Cyan    0;36
Red     0;31
Purple  0;35
Brown   0;33
Blue    0;34
Green   0;32
Cyan    0;36
Red     0;31
Purple  0;35
Brown   0;33
```

More info about color codes can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/).

Comment: This changes color of the secondary prompt. How to change primary color?

Comment: No, this changes the primary prompt (PS1). And what do you mean by primary color?